# /srv/share/ykant3/pythia/vector_cache/wiki.en.bin cannot be opened for loading

Tags: python, text, vision, transformer-model

I want to run pre-trained data at https://github.com/yashkant/sam-textvqa

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with this problem using deepmatcher. The reason why the wiki.en.bin wasn't loading was that it was trying to download the file directly from googledrive even though it wasn't explicitly telling me that was downloading the file.
What I did to make this work is the following found in this ticket:
https://github.com/anhaidgroup/deepmatcher/issues/57#issuecomment-684069856

```
wget https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/fasttext/vectors-wiki/wiki.en.zip --directory-prefix=/root/.vector_cache
unzip /root/.vector_cache/wiki.en.zip -d /root/.vector_cache/
rm /root/.vector_cache/wiki.en.vec
```

Make sure the path is where your model is expecting it and see if there is some specific path configuration to point the code to the wiki.en.bin.

Hopefully, this helps you even though it's a different package.